# .net core MVC One of my buttons in a foreach look doesn't fire javascript function

Tags: javascript, razor, asp.net-core-mvc

I've got this simple button in a partial view which worked well until i tried to test them all. Only the first button doesn't want to work:

```
~foreach(var item in collection){

    @if(ViewBag.AffichagePanier)
    {
        <button type="button" onclick="Ajouter('@item.IdVersion','@item.IdProduit', '@item.IdStatus',  @(item.Garantie ?? "-1"), '@item.TypeLicence')">
            <img src="~/images/panier.gif" alt="Panier" />
        </button>
    }
```

}
function Ajouter(version, Id_produit, id_status, garantie, type_licence) {

```
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: 'someUrl',
        ascync: true,
        data: { IdVersion: version, IdProduit: Id_produit, id_status: id_status, id_garantie: garantie, TypeLicence: type_licence },
        success: function () {                
            window.location.href = 'someUrl';
        }
    });
};~
```

And yet every item of the collection deals with the same model. 
I'm stuck as it seems (in firefox debugger) that the first button doesn't have any event attached to it.

Comment: Could you add the foreach part of the code and your onclick function? Also describe what you're button is supposed to do so we understand what "working" means.

Comment: thanks for your reply . The code create five buttons that trigger java function but not the first button . My buttons sends parameters  to a js function whitch makes anajax call.

Comment: Make sure whether the js function is not hit at all or it comes into ji function but your ajax has error.You could press F12 to check the source code of you rendered view

Comment: I found the key of the mystery: One of the items has a parameter with a quote. When I remove it , it works. Thank you guys .